# Prettier automatically adds {" "}

Tags: javascript, prettier

When I try to formatting the below code with Prettier:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View className="h-full flex flex-row justify-center bg-blue-500">
<View className="h-fit">
        <Text className="bg-red-500">THIS WILL BE CENTERED</Text>
  
</View>      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

It becomes:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View className="h-full flex flex-row justify-center bg-blue-500">
      <View className="h-fit">
        <Text className="bg-red-500">THIS WILL BE CENTERED</Text>
      </View>{" "}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Please note that Prettier automatically adds `{" "}` between the View and StatusBar tag. I don't want this behaviour to ever occur. How do I fix it?

Want to stop Prettier from writing {" "}

Comment: Don't write spaces between your elements in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Prettier is adding `{" "}` because it is probably parsing the line

```
</View>      <StatusBar style="auto" />
```

as needing a [white space](https://techstacker.com/how-to-add-white-space-between-elements-react-jsx/) between the innermost View element and the StatusBar element, which is not your intention. You can avoid this problem by leaving a newline between the elements you want to structure, i.e.,

```
</View>      
<StatusBar style="auto" />
```

This should "nudge" Prettier to format your code as you intend.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, everything you have stated is correct. However, is there a way to prevent it in all cases, even if I were trying to format ```</View>      <StatusBar...```?

Comment: @Aaspreet No, you cannot configure prettier to do that. It will format your code without changing its meaning, it will never break it.

Comment: @Asapreet Sorry. That is not possible, as Bergi commented. To quote from Prettier [design philosophy](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy): "Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated."

Answer (score 0):

It happens, I'd advise to avoid adding unnecessary space in the codebase.

```
<View className="h-fit">
  <Text className="bg-red-500">THIS WILL BE CENTERED</Text>
</View>
<StatusBar style="auto" />
```

You can leave it or ignore if it doesn't mess-up your code.